# Jupyter Notebook Custom Service

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to write a new service for Jupyter Notebook. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to run. I've created a service similar to the default services found here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/tree/master/notebook/services.

I'm attempting to run it in a Docker container built from `jupyter/base-notebook`. I've added `c.NotebookApp.extra_services = ['TestHandler']` to the Notebook config and I've copied my service to `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/test.py`.

When I start the Notebook server I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TestHandler'` so obviously my service is not being loaded correctly. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to load a service in Jupyter Notebook.

This is my `test.py` service:

```
import json

from tornado import web

from ...base.handlers import APIHandler


class TestHandler(APIHandler):

    @web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        res = { "foo": "bar" }
        self.finish(json.dumps(res))

default_handlers = [
    (r"/api/test", TestHandler),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That config value expects a list of importable modules which have a `default_handlers` attribute. You can therefore either use a full path:

```py
# assuming your `test.py` lives in a top level package `mypackage`
c.NotebookApp.extra_services = ['mypackage.test']
```

Alteratively you can directly construct a module:

```py
import sys
from types import ModuleType

name = 'some_long_ass_name_that_doesnt_conflict'
sys.modules[name] = ModuleType(name)  # make the import machinery find it
sys.modules[name].default_handlers = [...]

c.NotebookApp.extra_services = [name]
```